# How to create a kml map overlay?

Tags: dictionary, overlay, kml

I am trying to understand a KML Ground Overlay Tutorial, which has the following code as an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Folder>
    <name>Ground Overlays</name>
    <description>Examples of ground overlays</description>
    <GroundOverlay>
      <name>Large-scale overlay on terrain</name>
      <description>Overlay shows Mount Etna erupting 
          on July 13th, 2001.</description>
      <Icon>
        <href>https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/images/etna.jpg</href>
      </Icon>
      <LatLonBox>
        <north>37.91904192681665</north>
        <south>37.46543388598137</south>
        <east>15.35832653742206</east>
        <west>14.60128369746704</west>
        <rotation>-0.1556640799496235</rotation>
      </LatLonBox>
    </GroundOverlay>
  </Folder>
</kml>
```

There is no API key number, so I assume this KML is intended to be combined with a map of some sort.

I saved the kml to a publicly accessable file: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx17tEcqrzavTlc4ZHVmNFgyM1k/view?usp=sharing

Surely I must make an embedded map with some reference to this kml file.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide
The first example here uses iframe, it uses Place Mode, which I don't want.

```
<iframe
  width="600"
  height="450"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=YOUR_API_KEY
    &q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

View mode seems most appropriate of the above link options.

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view
  ?key=YOUR_API_KEY
  &center=-33.8569,151.2152
  &zoom=18
  &maptype=satellite
```

Oviously this needs to be recentered to Mt Etna,and my API key:

```
ttps://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view
  ?key=AIzaSyCrzeJMzJcHGCZj26Y9tHhmkSQ1zzJi8o0
  &center=37.91904192681665,15.35832653742206
  &zoom=14
  &maptype=satellite
```

Does it need to be put in iframe?

How can I combine these two chunks of code to create a kml map overlay embedded in my website?

Is there a way of doing this without using Java?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kml

Comment: http://googlemapsapi.blogspot.com/2007/03/kml-and-georss-support-added-to-google.html

Answer (score 0):

A KML file will not render directly on the web... it needs to be rendered on some map.  The easiest way to view a KML file yourself is to open it with Google Earth. If you want to put it on the web, one easy way is to use the Google Maps JavaScript API to embed a map on your site, and then use the KmlLayer function to add the KML file to the map.  Details and sample code are in the documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kml

Note that the copy of the KML file which you have on Google Drive will not open directly in Earth or anywhere else with the URL you provided, since it takes you to the Google Drive page for that file. Instead, you want to generate the direct download URL for that file on Drive, or put it online somewhere else.